# blank page from jsp or servlet when session invalidates

Tags: jsp, servlets, session-variables

I have session variables in JSP or servlet and anytime the session dies, the page become blank on screen when it is called. Has anyone got an idea about how i could manage the session such that another page is called when the session timeout reaches its value in web.xml? What i did was to check a value of a session variable in jsp or servlet(just below the body tag in jsp) if it is null then redirect control to the homepage of website but it still shows a blank page. So a user is forced to relaunch the website whenever the session get invalid.

```
<c:if test="${datax==null}">
 <c:redirect url="index.jsp"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Post your code where you have been validating the session.

Comment: Vinoth, i have edited my first post.

Comment: Are you sure, your current page and index.jsp page were in same directory (folder). Post your folder structure screenshot too.

Comment: they are in  the same directory. index.jsp is displayed when i call the page directly without any value in session. Just that when a user stays a long time without interacting with the system, the session expires and it shows a blank page.

Comment: It means always the session is null, check where you setting the session. I mean in servlet just check before redirecting to your page. Add your servlet code (where the session is being set). We can't help anything with these code

Comment: Usually, the "blank page" symptom is indicative that an exception occurred while server is busy generating HTML output, resulting in distupted/halfbaked HTML output. Checking response body and server logs should give clues.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have declared your session timeout in your `web.xml`.
so you can use a servlet `Filter` to get the job done.

e.g.:

```js
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);// create if it doesn't exist
if(session != null && !session.isNew()) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
}
```

also you can use a flagging mechanism to see if the `session.isNew()` set the flag to `true` , else make it `false`. then redirect to the index page accordingly.

there are more ways to achieve the same bro, just surf !
hope this will help you : [link](http://www.java-only.com/LoadTutorial.javaonly?id=12)!